# Random slow querys in SQL Server in longrunning mass data migration process

Tags: sql-server

We have do migrate data from another huge db to our db using tons of sql scripts. To do this a fast way, we drop most of all indexes from our destination db.

Now, in a not repeatable way, some queries tending to run for minutes an hours instead of minutes. It are not always the same queries. If we stop the hole migration for a time, and then repeat the query, it runs fast again.

So it seems, sql server sometimes chooses wrong execution paths or is having other problems. How should we approach this problem?

Comment: If you dropped your indexes, this hardly seems surprising at all. How do you expect complex queries to behave ? Did you take a look at the *execution plan* of your queries ? Also, there might be some caching involved so that your queries could seem faster sometimes.

Comment: How are you migrating data? Bulk copy? Manual statements and linked servers? SSIS? Something else? How many rows at a time? Regardless of process, if you're reading old, normally not-accessed data in order to copy it, more recent data that queries are likely to need will be pushed out of the buffer pool. Whether that's the actual cause is another matter -- it could also be locking, depending on the technology you're using for the copy.

Comment: Could be anything. You could be running out of memory. Your network card could be running on low power mode. You need to try and isolate the issue. I suggest you download and install `sp_WhoIsActive` and observe these slow queries

Comment: We dropped the indexes on the dest database so insert isn't slowed down by them.

Comment: @JeroenMostert We move data like this: 
INSERT INTO NewDB.dbo.XY .. Select ... FROM SourceDB.dbo.YZ.